# Differentiate between two set of points

Tags: clustering, k-means, coherence

Consider two sets of points (in the pictures below), whose **"`center of gravity`" is same**. What measure can differentiate between the two sets?

*e.g.*

Image 1 and 2 has both `16` points, whose average comes to the same point for both the sets. I wanted to know what measure can be used to differentiate between the both. **How can I say points in image 2 are more cohesive compared to the other.** *(not sure if "cohesive" is the correct term for this, but I hope you get the idea)*

I **dont** want to use `k-means` because it will too expensive to calculate the clusters for every sets, and I have around millions of them.

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a specialized "cohesiveness" metric. However, if you average over all points the distances to your closest n points (e.g. using n=1), together with the variance of that calculation, you should get your required information.

In your provided example, averaging over all points the distance to the closest next point (n=1) will give you the large, roughly uniform distances between points for Image 1 and the small, roughly uniform inner-cluster distances for Image 2. The homogenity (i.e. uniformity of the distances and hence, cohesiveness of the points) will be evidences by the low variance of the average distance.

If you then explore averaging the distances to your closest 2, 3, 4, ... points, the distance and variance should slowly increase and you should find a sort of "tipping point" giving you information about identifiable cluster sizes. (However, this should not be relevant for the cohesiveness argument.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fit a clustering algorithm, one option could be to use silhouette width as an evaluation metric to compare fits across datasets. Silhouette width evaluates the separation between clusters. In Image 2, there is more separation and will have larger silhouette width.

As far as scaling up to millions of data points, silhouette width has an approximate version that is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different metrics of spatial uniformity. E.g. this paper: [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmsy.2012.07.018)]. These measures are broadly divided into quadrat-based and distance-based.

In quadrat-based methods, divide your space into quadrats, then take your data, $x$, count how many points $x_i$ are in each quadrat $i$, and build different metrics using those counts, their mean, $\bar x$, standard deviation, $s$, and maybe higher moments.

Distance-based metrics use different functional summaries of the distances between points.

For example, the simplest quadrat-based metric is the index of dispersion: $ID = (q-1)s^2/\bar x$, where $q$ is the number of quadrats. Let's divide the data from your pictures into quadrats and calculate the index of dispersion for each.

[image]

For the first picture, $x = [2,3,2,3,2,1,1,1]$, and $ID = 2.971$. For the second picture, $x = [0,8,0,1,5,0,0,2,0]$, and $ID = 36.875$ which is much higher. The index of dispersion will be larger if the data are clustered.

Other quadrat-based methods include skewness index, Moran's I, Geary's C, Local Moran's I, Local Gi, Global Shannon entropy, Global–local Shannon entropy. For details, see the paper that I referenced, or search in the Internet.

Distance-based metrics include the cumulative distribution function of distances from a randomly selected location to its nearest point, $F(r)$, the cumulative distribution function of distances from a randomly selected point to its nearest neighbor, $G(r)$, various combinations of $F(r)$ and $G(r)$, for example $J(r) = (1-G(r))/(1-F(r))$, and other.

[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmsy.2012.07.018) Kin Ming Kam, Li Zeng, Qiang Zhou, Richard Tran, Jian Yang, On assessing spatial uniformity of particle distributions in quality control of manufacturing processes, Journal of Manufacturing Systems, V32, 1, 2013, 154-166,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmsy.2012.07.018.